# Perl - "Complex" Data Structure

Tags: perl, data-structures

I'm trying to get a workable data structure that I can pull the element values from in a sensible fashion. Just having great difficulty working with the data once its in the structure. This is how the struct is built:

```
sub hopCompare
{

    my %count;
    my %master;
    my $index = 0;

    foreach my $objPath (@latest)    #get Path object out of master array
    {
            my @path = @{$objPath->_getHopList()}; #dereferencing
            my $iter = 0;
            foreach my $hop (@path)
            {

                    ++$count{$hop}->{FREQ};
                    $count{$hop}->{INDEX} = $index;
                    $count{$hop}->{NODE} = $hop;

                    $index++;

            }
            $index = 0;
    }
    foreach my $element( keys %count )
    {
            if (defined($count{$element}->{NODE}))
            {
                    my $curr = $count{$element}->{INDEX};
                    my $freq = $count{$element}->{FREQ};
                    if (($freq > 1) || ($count{$element}->{INDEX} =~ /[0-1]/))
                    {
                            push @{ $master{$curr} }, {$count{$element}->{NODE}, {FREQ => $count{$element}->{FREQ}}};
                    }
                    print "$element = $count{$element}\n";
                    print "$element Index = $count{$element}->{INDEX}\n";
            }
    }
    print "\n Master contains: \n" . Dumper (%master);
    if (%master){return %master;} else {die "NO FINAL HOPS MATCHED";}
```

}

Producing this structure:

%Master contains:

```
$VAR1 = '4';
$VAR2 = [
      {
        '1.1.1.2' => {
                              'FREQ' => 2
                            }
      }
    ];
$VAR3 = '1';
$VAR4 = [
      {
        '1.1.1.9' => {
                              'FREQ' => 5
                            }
      },
      {
        '1.1.1.8' => {
                              'FREQ' => 1
                            }
      }
    ];

    {truncated}
```

Although ideally the structure should look like this but I had even less joy trying to pull data out at sub identifyNode:

```
$VAR1 = {
      '1' => [
               {
                 '1.1.1.9' => {
                                       'FREQ' => 5
                                     }
               },
               {
                 '1.1.5.8' => {
                                       'FREQ' => 1
                                     }
               }
             ],
```

Then to get back at the data in another method I'm using:

```
 sub identifyNode
 {
    my %hops = %{$_[0]};
    my $i = 0;

    foreach my $h ( keys %hops )                   #The HOP-INDEX is the key
    {
            print "\n\$h looks like \n" . Dumper ($hops{$h});
            my %host = %{ $hops{$h}[0] };           #Push the first HASH in INDEX to the %host HASH
            foreach my $hip (keys %host)
            {
                            my $corelink = `corelinks $hip`;

                            my ($node) = $corelink =~ /([a-z0-9-]+),[a-z0-9-\/]+,$hip/s;
                            print "\n\t\t\tHostname is $node\n";
            }
            $i++;
    }

}
```

This then generates:

```
$h looks like
$VAR1 = [
      {
        '1.1.1.2' => {
                              'FREQ' => 2
                            }
      }
    ];

                    Hostname is blabla-bla-a1

$h looks like
$VAR1 = [
      {
        '1.1.1.9' => {
                              'FREQ' => 5
                            }
      },
      {
        '1.1.1.8' => {
                              'FREQ' => 1
                            }
      }
    ];

                    Hostname is somew-some-a1
```

So for each hash in $h only the topmost host gets evaluated and hostname returned. This is because it is told to do so by the [0] in line:

```
my %host = %{ $hops{$h}[0] };
```

I've played around with different data structures and de-referencing the structure a multitude of ways and this is the only halfway house I've found...

(The IPs have been obfuscated so are not consistent in my examples)

Comment: `print Dumper(\%master)`

Comment: I am not sure what the problem is exactly, but for one you need to dereference (and iterate over) at every level.  So instead of `%{ $hops{$h}[0] }` have `for my $e (@{$hops{$h}}) { my %host = %{ $hops{$h}[$e] } .. }` (if I got your nesting right).  More to the point, when complex structures get too unwieldy it's a hint to write a class instead.

Comment: Any time I see 'complex data structure' I think 'try writing it as OO'. Because that's pretty much what OO is _for_.

Comment: Thanks Zdim I'll have a go at your approach though I think its something I've attempted..chances are my syntax was slightly off!

Comment: Yeah Sobrique changing it to OO was done however once a hop object was defined I had the same issue of iterating through each IP and FREQ contained under that hop. There's a design pattern I need to apply here but it's escaping my mind..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your advice it got me halfway there. It works now (in still somewhat a convoluted fashion!) :

```
sub identifyNode
{
    my %hops = %{$_[0]};
    my $i = 0;
    my @fin_nodes;
    my $hindex;

    foreach my $h ( keys %hops )                   #The HOP-INDEX is the key
    {
            $hindex = $h;

            foreach my $e (@{$hops{$h}})       #first part of solution credit Zdim
            {
                    my @host = %{ $e };      #second part of solution
                    my $hip = $host[0];
                    my $corelink = `corelinks $hip`;
                    my ($node) = $corelink =~ /([a-z0-9-]+),[a-z0-9-\/]+,$hip/s;
                    print "\n\t\t\tHostname is $node\n";

                    push (@fin_nodes, [$node, $hindex, $e->{$hip}->{FREQ}]);
            }
            $i++;
    }
    return (\@fin_nodes);
}
```

Am I brave enough to add  the data as a hash to @fin_nodes.. hmm